# Get access to variable from thymeleaf and change color of the each line in table according to value of variable

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf, variable-assignment

I work with Java, Spring and Thymeleaf. I'm trying to make a table where the following data would be listed, each person in one line.

```
<tr class="tr-frame" id="tr-one-line" th:each="woundedPerson: ${woundedPeople}">
        <td class="td-ident" th:text="${woundedPerson.getIdent()}"></td>
        <td class="td-name" th:text="${woundedPerson.getName()}"></td>
        <td class="td-surname" th:text="${woundedPerson.getSurname()}"></td>
        <td class="td-index" id="td-ind" th:text="${woundedPerson.getColorIndex()}"></td>
        <td class="td-date-time" th:text="${woundedPerson.getAddAt()}"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to know, how can I change color of line according to value of th:text="${woundedPerson.getColorIndex()}"? Value can be red, green, black and yellow. Any help please?

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116655/how-to-set-color-in-td-with-thymeleaf or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016897/thymeleaf-into-style-style

Comment: ++ https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-tr-bgcolor-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what are the example values of woundedPerson.getColorIndex().

You can add a class on your tr tag using th:classappend

```
<tr th:classappend="${woundedPerson.getColorIndex() == 'blue' ? 'class_name' : 'different_class_name'}" >
```

or a style

```
<tr th:style="${woundedPerson.getColorIndex() == 'blue' ? 'background-color:blue' : ''}" >
```